# requests.get(link, headers=headers).json() fails to load but on browser it load ok

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I am trying to access an url with requests.get but on terminal I always get this error:

```
Failed to open https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/rpc/getListedNFTsByQuery?q=%7B%22%24match%22%3A%7B%22collectionSymbol%22%3A%22meekolony%22%7D%2C%22%24sort%22%3A%7B%22takerAmount%22%3A1%2C%22createdAt%22%3A-1%7D%2C%22%24skip%22%3A0%2C%22%24limit%22%3A5%7D
```

However if I click that same link to open it on browser it loads just fine.
Here is some part of the code:

```
link = "https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/rpc/getListedNFTsByQuery?q=%7B%22%24match%22%3A%7B%22collectionSymbol%22%3A%22"+str(nameCollection)+"%22%7D%2C%22%24sort%22%3A%7B%22takerAmount%22%3A1%2C%22createdAt%22%3A-1%7D%2C%22%24skip%22%3A0%2C%22%24limit%22%3A5%7D"
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.193 Safari/537.36'
}
# make the request from the website and convert the data into a JSON file
try:
    # print(resp) will show all the data collected
    resp = requests.get(link, headers=headers).json()
  
except:
    return None
```

It is strange because some weeks ago everything worked perfect. So maybe the website changed the way of accessing data recently?

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: You're not checking the HTTP status code. It's probably a 403 which could arise because you've hit some kind of limits for requests from your IP address. They may have something like CloudFlare as their defence mechanism. I am able to execute this code without issues but the chances are that if I try it repeatedly I will eventually get the same issue you're seeing

Comment: Hmmm it might be that, but why can I access via browser if they supposedly blocked my Ip?

Comment: To answer that you will need to debug your browser activity. What you will see is confirmation that CloudFlare is intercepting and rejecting your request. CloudFlare has several techniques to attempt to block bots, one of which is TLS fingerprinting. Using that mechanism it can determine whether (or not) the client is a real browser. This issue has been addressed many times on stack**overflow**.

Answer (score 0):

You may have more success with urllib3 as follows:

```
import sys
import io
import json
import urllib3

URL = 'https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/rpc/getListedNFTsByQuery?q={"$match":{"collectionSymbol":"meekolony"},"$sort":{"takerAmount":1,"createdAt":-1},"$skip":0,"$limit":5}'

HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0'
}


with urllib3.PoolManager() as http:
    try:
        if (r := http.request('GET', URL, headers=HEADERS, preload_content=False)).status != 200:
            raise Exception(f'HTTP status {r.status}')
        r.auto_close = False
        j = json.load(io.TextIOWrapper(r))
        print(json.dumps(j, indent=2))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, file=sys.stderr)
```